# Overlap table cells

Tags: tables

I use "multicol" to create a page with two columns and in one column I have a table. My problem is that the table is too wide and I get an "Overfull \hbox" warning. Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
Text
\vfill\columnbreak\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}lr@{}}
\textbf{Textext extextext:} & Text \\
\textbf{Text:} & Text \\
\textbf{Text:} & Textextextete xtextextext \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I want that some of the cells overlap the cell next to it (see picture). Is it possible?
[image: Example picture: Overlapping cells]

Comment: use a 3-column table and \multicolum to make the first cell span col 1-2 and the last cell span col 2-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a 3-column table and `\multicolum` to make the first cell span col 1-2 and the last cell span col 2-3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
Text
\vfill\columnbreak\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Textext extextext:}} & Text \\
\textbf{Text:} && Text \\
\textbf{Text:} & \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{Textextextete xtextextext} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```